# domain change in a multisite environment

Tags: 7, migrations, multi-sites, subsites

I have 2 sites in a multisite environment. one is www.mycompany.com installed at `public_html/mycompany.com` main directory of the drupal core and uses `sites/all` folder

I have another site www.sub.mycompany.com using the folder `public_html/mycompany.com/sites/sub.mycompany.com`

I want to change their domain names. I want www.sub.mycompany.com to be in www.mycompany.com and want www.mycompany.com to be in www.sub2.mycompany.com

so www.sub.mycompany.com won't be used anymore

how to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the example.sites.php file that ships with D7?

Comment: yea but I do not understand how it works please tell me how can I use that file for do what I need?  *o*

Comment: Ok. The comments in that file are pretty verbose. You'll have to tell us what's not working when you try to follow the instructions in it for us to help. Otherwise you can use a symlink to alias the current directory names to the new names. That's what I used to do back in Drupal 6.

Comment: Interesting question, which gets asked so now and then (+1!). Do you "only" want to change the domain names, or do you at the same time want to rework the folder structure of your multi site setup? Extra question: are you using a lot (or only a few, maybe none) of images or files (like PDFs) that are included (like an img) in your nodes or attached to such nodes (which are typically stored in your public/private files folder, such as in sites/default/files)?